# Yii Framework (v1.1): проблема с алиасом в URL при наличии пагинации

Tags: php, yii

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой - в конфигурации компонента CUrlManager среди прочих есть правило:

```
'/category/<slug>/' => '/site/category'
```

при этом значения атрибутов компонента таковы:

```
'class' => 'CUrlManager',
'urlFormat' => 'path',
'urlSuffix' => '',
'showScriptName' => false,
'cacheID' => 'cache',
'useStrictParsing' => true,
```

Правило говорит о том, что ссылки вида http://site.ru/category/custom-alias/ должен обрабатывать actionCategory() контроллера SiteController, здесь все понятно и пока работает. Но как только я "завел" на странице пагинацию, то столкнулся со следующей проблемой: вместо желаемой ссылки http://site.ru/category/custom-alias/?page=2 пагинатор выдает http://site.ru/category/?slug=custom-alias&page=2. Не могу понять что и где я упустил.
Буду благодарен за помощь, заранее спасибо всем неравнодушным откликнувшимся! :)

UPD.: стоит отметить, что "неправильную" ссылку вида http://site.ru/category/?slug=custom-alias&page=2 генерит сам пагинатор, но при этом текущая страница также без проблем доступна по "нужной" ссылке http://site.ru/category/custom-alias/?page=2, что не будет хорошо для поисковой оптимизации. Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать единственно верное правило для доступности ссылки по паттерну вида http://site.ru/category/custom-alias/?page=2 и только нему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось в следующем - поскольку кроме упомянутого правила присутствовало ещё одно:

```
'/category/' => '/site/category',
'/category/<slug>/' => '/site/category'
```

то обращение двух роутов к одному и тому же экшену и повлекло за собой вышеописанную ошибку. После их разделения на

```
'/category/' => '/site/category',
'/category/<slug>/' => '/site/ShowCategory'
```

проблема исчезла.